# javascript how to direct browser's "back" button to a different web address?

Tags: javascript, html, button, back

I would like to direct the visitor to a different link, once he clicks the "back" button on his browser. I know that it can be done :)

I tried to play with the history of the browser but it didn't work

Thanks!

Elad

Comment: How do you know it can be done if you don't know how to do it? Is the link you want to take them to on the same origin (domain)?

Comment: Read about the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History)

Comment: Is this url on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate and I deleted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this will work since i have never tried this..but here you go:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate',function() {
window.location.href="www.example.com"/*url you want";
}
```

You can refer this for further information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Comment: I did something similar and it worked for me. As long as it's on the same origin